# É possivel ultilizar uma variavel em Strings.xml

Tags: android, android-xml

Estou tentando fazer com que uma string do string.xml substitua um campo na tela, porem andei pesquisando e não estou conseguindo usa-la como variavel

string.xml

```
<string name="nome">%1$s</string>
```

classe.java

```
Resources res = getResources();
        String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.nome), username);
```

layout.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nome1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/nome"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é exactamente o que está a pensar, mas pode fazer algo assim:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = res.getString(R.string.nome, username);
textView.setText(text);
```

Tendo como exemplo a sua string, isto não tem qualquer utilidade.

Um exemplo em que pode ser útil é no uso de strings por idioma:

```
<string name="nome">My name is %1$s</string>
```

e

```
<string name="nome">O meu nome é %1$s</string>
```

A parte inicial é escolhida automaticamente, de acordo com o idioma, sendo depois inserido o nome.

Comment: Ah sim, então não há maneira de inserir os dados na string.xml pela classe do java ?

Comment: Que eu saiba não.

Comment: É que na verdade eu tentei inserir direto no campo que mostro na imagem, porem não funcionou

Comment: Pois ao tentar inserir o texto, naquela TextView o aplicativo 'crashava'

Comment: Certo, então eu substituiria no meu xml por esse e ele supostamente trocaria?

Comment: Julgo que a sua dificuldade nada tem haver com a pergunta que fez. Se o que quer saber é como alterar aquele TextView via java é melhor fazer outra pergunta(para não invalidar esta) do género: **Como alterar o texto da HeaderView da NavigationView?**

Comment: Ah sim obrigado, eu estava tentando do modo que fiz a pergunta, porem você disse que não funcionaria